# on click event for multiple buttons with same class

Tags: javascript, html, liquid

I have a component that is populated multiple times in the page. Inside that component I have a button that on click hides some content and shows another.

What I'm expecting: on click of each button it should execute initAnswer() function.

What I have now: Once I click on the button nothing is happening and I get no error.

P.S. I have checked other threads and tried to replicate the answers but with no success. Thank you!!!

```js
let selectedShadeButton = document.querySelectorAll('.shade-btn');

let shadeDataSet = selectedShadeButton.dataset.sheertexShade;

for(let i = 0; i < selectedShadeButton.length; i++) {

selectedShadeButton[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(event = event.target){
    initAnswer();
  }
})

}

function initAnswer() {
  document.querySelector('.nudes-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.nudes-thanks').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.shady-answer').innerHTML = shadeDataSet;
}
```

```html
<div id="nudesModal" class="modalnudes">

{% comment %} Modal content {% endcomment %}
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close-nudespop">&times;</span>
    <div class="inner-content">
    <p class="sm:tw-text-4xl tw-leading-tight sm:tw-ml-auto pop-title tw-text-2xl">Which group should we start from?</p>
    <p>The subtitle of the modal</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nudes-wrapper tw-flex">
      <div class="shade-container">
        {% include 'shade-picker.row', shade_name: 'S1' %}
        {% include 'shade-picker.row', shade_name: 'S2' %}
        {% include 'shade-picker.row', shade_name: 'S3' %}
        {% include 'shade-picker.row', shade_name: 'S4' %}
        {% include 'shade-picker.row', shade_name: 'S5' %}
        {% include 'shade-picker.row', shade_name: 'S6' %}
      </div>
      <div class="magnified-img">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nudes-thanks tw-hidden">
    {% include 'nudes-thank-you' %}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


/* inside the shade-picker.row */

<div class="shade-{{shade_name}} shade-of-nude">
  <label>{{ shade_name }}</label>
  <div class="shade-img tw-flex">
    <img class="lazyload" data-src="{{ shade_name | append: '-face1.jpg' | asset_url }}" data-sizes="auto" alt="Picture of a face that matches shade {{shade_name | escape}}">
    <img class="lazyload" data-src="{{ shade_name | append: '-face2.jpg' | asset_url }}" data-sizes="auto" alt="Picture of a face that matches shade {{shade_name | escape}}">
    <img class="lazyload" data-src="{{ shade_name | append: '-face3.jpg' | asset_url }}" data-sizes="auto" alt="Picture of a face that matches shade {{shade_name | escape}}">
    <img class="lazyload" data-src="{{ shade_name | append: '-face4.jpg' | asset_url }}" data-sizes="auto" alt="Picture of a face that matches shade {{shade_name | escape}}"> 
    <noscript>
      <img class="lazyloaded" data-src="{{ shade_name | append: '-face1.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Picture of a face that matches shade {{shade_name | escape}}">
      <img class="lazyloaded" data-src="{{ shade_name | append: '-face2.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Picture of a face that matches shade {{shade_name | escape}}">
      <img class="lazyloaded" data-src="{{ shade_name | append: '-face3.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Picture of a face that matches shade {{shade_name | escape}}">
      <img class="lazyloaded" data-src="{{ shade_name | append: '-face4.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="Picture of a face that matches shade {{shade_name | escape}}"> 
    </noscript>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="shade-btn" data-sheertex-shade='{{shade_name}}'>Pick {{ shade_name }}!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is by doing this

```
let selectedShadeButton = document.querySelectorAll('.shade-btn');
```

You will receive an array of nodes in the selectedShadeButton and on that array of nodes you can not access dataset. So dataset is undefined. To solve the problem you can debug the problem by doing some debugging.

```
console.log(selectedShadeButton)
```

Will help you to understand what is happening